# How can I start Norton Commander on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, midnight-commander, norton-commander

Is it installed by default? If yes, how can i started it. If no, how can I installed it?

**ADDED:**
I need something free.

Comment: Why would Norton Commander be installed by default? And what does it do?

Comment: I thought that it is kind of old DOS program from browsing directories  end editing files. I just got to use midnight commander in Linux and I like it. I thought that Windows can have something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download and install Norton Commander from [here](http://www.winnc.com/norton_commander_download).

Instead of Norton Commander, I recommend you [**FreeCommander**](http://www.freecommander.com/) as a free and very good solution.

Comment: Well, I need to buy it... I need something free.

Comment: Please see my edited answer...

Comment: Thats good. Thank you. I have installed it and tried. But unfortunately it does not have a text editor with highlighting.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/38951/free-alternative-to-total-commander for all possible alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

you should use Total Commander . Norton Commander is old enough , don't let him "play" anymore .

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative is [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/). It's gone open-source, and was initially by the people behind the RAR archiver. Lots of plugins are available too, allowing some quite powerful features.

Answer (score 0):

Norton Commander for Windows and DOS are no longer compatible for Windows.  The best clone, hands down, I have found is a free product called "Double Commander".

Double Commander versions can be found for Linux, Windows and Mac both 32 bit and 64 bit.  The GUI can be customized and the product can use most Total Commander plugins.  Unlike Total Commander, Double Commander is freeware.